# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer average_pooling2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset of 2 class with 102 images all. Each image contains 9 blocks. After split the data the shape as the following:
`X_train shape: (71, 9, 64, 64, 1)`, where 71 the no. of images. 9 blocks. `64*64` block dim.
`X_test shape: (31, 9, 64, 64, 1)`, where 31 the no. of images. 9 blocks. `64*64` block dim.

I want to enter every 9 sequences of image blocks (that related to single image) at the same time to the same CNN structure. I use TimeDistributed and conv2d to do that, but I'm confusing with input shape, it returns the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer average_pooling2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5
```

My model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False), input_shape=(9, 64, 64, 1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation(activation='relu'))
model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2))
        
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation(activation='relu'))
model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2))
        
model.add(Conv2D(32, (1, 1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation(activation='relu'))
model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2))
     
model.add(Conv2D(64, (1, 1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation(activation='relu'))
model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2))
        
model.add(Conv2D(128, (1, 1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation(activation='relu'))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
       
model.summary()
```

The summary until the first `AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2)` is:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
time_distributed_1 (TimeDist (None, 9, 64, 64, 8)      72        
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 9, 64, 64, 8)      32        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 9, 64, 64, 8)      0         
=================================================================
Total params: 104
Trainable params: 88
Non-trainable params: 16
_________________________________________________________________
```

when debugging the code, the error occurs in the first `AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2))`. Please any one can help me to correct that code.

Comment: You need to wrap _all_ convolution and pooling layers in `TimeDistributed`.

Comment: I'm trying this